# Flume spooldir to get file metadata of source file

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I have a requirement where in for each flume event I have to add filename and file creationdate of a file in spooldir directoy. I have found that I can add filename in header of event by setting fileHeader=true. Simillarly Can I also find file creation date by writing some custom interceptor ?

Comment: did u get any answer

Answer (score 0):

The file name is set within the Spool Source implementation:

```
if (annotateFileName) {
  String filename = currentFile.get().getFile().getAbsolutePath();
  for (Event event : events) {
    event.getHeaders().put(fileNameHeader, filename);
  }
}
```

That's a specific implementation detail of that Source type. If you want to preserve the originla file name, you need to set the property, these are the available options:

```
fileHeader  false   Whether to add a header storing the absolute path filename.
fileHeaderKey   file    Header key to use when appending absolute path filename to event header.
```

If you want to add a timestamp, you can actually use built-in interceptors:

- TimestampInterceptor for timestamp
- Host Interceptor for the flume instance's hostname
- StaticInterceptor for any constant value.